Inside Docker No Internet Connection in cwl
I am trying to download data from the URL. I created the docker image called download-files that downloads the CSV files. When I run the docker command I can download the files however, if I try to incorporate that docker image inside the cwltool and then execute it I am getting an error and the message that the Internet Connection is not available.
This is my cwlfile that I have executed.
class: CommandLineTool

hints:
  DockerRequirement:
    dockerPull: download-files

inputs:
  url:
    type: string
    inputBinding:
      position: 1

outputs:
  output_csv:
    type: File
    outputBinding:
      glob: "*.csv"

This is my docker file that I have created to download the files
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY ExtractData.py .

RUN pip install requests

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/app/ExtractData.py"]


This is the python script
import requests
import sys

def download_file(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        filename =  url.split('/')[-1]
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print(f"File downloaded: {filename}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download file from {url}")
def check_internet_connection():
  try:
    response = requests.get("https://www.google.com", timeout=3) 
    response.raise_for_status() 
    return True
  except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, requests.exceptions.Timeout) as e:
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("arguments passed to the script are :",sys.argv)
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python download_files.py <URL>")
        sys.exit(1)

    url = sys.argv[1]

    if check_internet_connection():
        print("Internet connection is available.")
    else:
        print("Internet connection is not available.")
    download_file(url)

The command that I used to execute the cwl is
cwltool dataset_extraction.cwl --url https://data.cdc.gov/resource/bugr-bbfr.csv # This is not working
The command that I used to execute the docker is
docker run download-files  https://data.cdc.gov/resource/bugr-bbfr.csv # This is working
